# How to evaluate a variable length in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I want to write a shell script, in which it will call different command according to the variable length. But I didn't figure it out yet.

My unwork script is here:

```
for i in n5 n25 
if ${#i} == 2;
then 
do 
    python two.py n5
elif ${#i} == 3;
do 
    python three.py n25
fi
```

How to evaluate the variable length in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
for i in n5 n25 
do
   if [ ${#i} -eq 2 ]; then 
       python two.py n5
   elif [ ${#i} -eq 3 ]; then
       python three.py n25
   fi
done
```

Note that:

- `for` goes with `do ... done`.
- `if` goes with `then ... [elif; then] ... [else; then] ... fi`.
- the integer comparisons need `-eq` (equal) instead of `=` (for strings) and are written within brackets (`if [ "$var" -eq 2 ]`, etc).

Comment: Can I nested another for loop inside such an if statement like above? The structure is like: for i in ... do .. if...then for j in... do ... done; fi done;

Comment: I tried, it worked. Amazing, thanks for your answer @fedorqui